# Override index operator for offset

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

In my project I need a "shifted" list.
Basically I have a `public class dyn_int : List<int>` to support some of our old scripts (written in a proprietary language, but "semi-auto-translated" to C#)

In that language, lists started their indices with 1, not with 0!

I currently try to create a convenience API so that our developers can still use the style they are familiar with.

I am however stuck at creating the index operator.
Here is my current implementation of the index-accessor for the lists.
The getter works fine, I am not sure what to do about the set method though.
I did not find a `List.SetElementAt(key, value)` method so far.

```
public class dyn_int : List<int> 
{
    public int this[int key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ElementAt(key-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `The getter works fine`... Have you tried `dyn_int[0]`?

Comment: I would *strongly* urge you to use composition rather than inheritance here (and to start following .NET naming conventions). Give your class a `List<int>` *variable* instead of deriving from `List<int>`, and make your class implement `IList<int>`... although even that's going to be "interesting" given the expectations of the indexer.

Comment: You should also not be using `ElementAt` to get items from a list.  You're iterating the entire sequence to get that node.

Comment: @JonSkeet's solution seems reasonable. it would solve my problem, as the index functions can still access the list's index functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick linqPad test. You would need to do some error handling, etc but this should get you going.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new CustomList<int>();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);

    list[1] = 5;
    list[1].Dump(); //output 5
}

public class CustomList<T>
{
    IList<T> list = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
       get
       {
           return list[index - 1];
       }
       set
       {
           list[index - 1] = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this solution (function add). However, I was looking for a way to use the indices also for the setting of elements directly.